# How do I unselect selected options in a multi Select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to detect if the option is selected but it's always is selected because I have an onclick on the `select`

```
function deselectSelected(elm){
        alert($(elm).find("option:selected").attr("selected")) //always returns selected
    }
```

Comment: You're finding all the options which are selected, and then alerting whether or not they're selected. Of course it will always alert selected...

Comment: You are looking for the selected item (`find("option:selected")` and then complain about its being selected ???

Comment: use if ( $('[selector]:visible') ) { // do something }

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#mySelectBox option').each(function() {
if($(this).is(':selected')) ...
```